# Modified record in Dojo Data Grid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, record

How can I get the modified records from a DOJO Data grid. Like in EXTJS we have an attribute named dirty which is set to true if the record is modified similarly do we have any attribute in dojo which says that the record is modified or is there any workaround for the same. Waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event onApplyCellEdit of the grid and create an array of changes or something similar. You can get the new value, the row index and the field index.

From the API:
onApplyCellEdit(inValue, inRowIndex, inFieldIndex) Event fired when editing is applied for a given grid cell

Comment: Thanks.. BTW i figured it out